Why does the code show only some white lines when you compiled it?
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h

.DATA
  COLUMNA DW ?
  FILA DW ?
  AVANCEH DW ?
  AVANCEV DW ?

.CODE

DETENER_POR_TIEMPO PROC
  MOV CX, 2000h
  MOV DX, 2000h
  MOV BX, 2000h
  NOP
  RET
DETENER_POR_TIEMPO ENDP

DIBUJARRECTANGULOGRIS PROC
  PUSH AX
  PUSH BX
  PUSH CX
  PUSH DX

  MOV AX, 0A000h   ; Segmento de la memoria de video
  MOV ES, AX

  MOV DI, COLUMNA   ; Columna inicial
  MOV AX, FILA      ; Fila inicial
  MOV BX, AVANCEH   ; Ancho del rectángulo
  MOV CX, AVANCEV   ; Alto del rectángulo

  MOV DX, BX        ; Ancho
  MOV BX, CX        ; Alto

  MOV AL, 8         ; Color gris

  DIBUJAR_FILA:
      MOV CX, DX    ; Restaura CX al ancho inicial
      REP STOSB     ; Dibuja una fila de píxeles
      ADD DI, 320   ; Avanza a la siguiente fila en la memoria de video
      DEC BX        ; Decrementa el alto
      JNZ DIBUJAR_FILA

  POP DX
  POP CX
  POP BX
  POP AX
  RET
DIBUJARRECTANGULOGRIS ENDP

DIBUJARCIRCULONEGRO PROC
  PUSH AX
  PUSH BX
  PUSH CX
  PUSH DX

  MOV AX, 0A000h   ; Segmento de la memoria de video
  MOV ES, AX

  MOV DI, COLUMNA   ; Columna inicial
  MOV AX, FILA      ; Fila inicial
  MOV BX, AVANCEH   ; Radio horizontal del círculo
  MOV CX, AVANCEV   ; Radio vertical del círculo

  MOV DX, BX        ; Radio horizontal
  MOV BX, CX        ; Radio vertical

  MOV AL, 1         ; Color negro

  DIBUJAR_CIRCULO:
      MOV CX, DX    ; Restaura CX al radio horizontal
      REP STOSB     ; Dibuja una fila de píxeles
      ADD DI, 320   ; Avanza a la siguiente fila en la memoria de video
      DEC BX        ; Decrementa el radio vertical
      JNZ DIBUJAR_CIRCULO

  POP DX
  POP CX
  POP BX
  POP AX
  RET
DIBUJARCIRCULONEGRO ENDP

DIBUJARTRIANGULODORADO PROC
  PUSH AX
  PUSH BX
  PUSH CX
  PUSH DX

  MOV AX, 0A000h   ; Segmento de la memoria de video
  MOV ES, AX

  MOV DI, COLUMNA   ; Columna inicial
  MOV AX, FILA      ; Fila inicial
  MOV BX, AVANCEH   ; Base del triángulo
  MOV CX, AVANCEV   ; Altura del triángulo

  MOV DX, BX        ; Base
  MOV BX, CX        ; Altura

  MOV AL, 14h       ; Color dorado

  DIBUJAR_LINEAS:
      MOV CX, DX    ; Restaura CX a la base del triángulo
      MOV DH, 0

      DIBUJAR_LINEA:
          MOV AL, 14h  ; Color dorado
          STOSB        ; Dibuja un píxel
          INC DI       ; Avanza al siguiente píxel en la memoria de video
          LOOP DIBUJAR_LINEA

      ADD DI, 320     ; Salta a la siguiente fila en la memoria de video
      DEC BX          ; Decrementa la altura
      JNZ DIBUJAR_LINEAS

  POP DX
  POP CX
  POP BX
  POP AX
  RET
DIBUJARTRIANGULODORADO ENDP

INICIO:
  MOV AX, @data
  MOV DS, AX

  MOV AX, 13h       ; Cambiar a modo gráfico 320x200
  INT 10h

  MOV COLUMNA, 120
  MOV FILA, 100
  MOV AVANCEH, 100
  MOV AVANCEV, 150
  CALL DIBUJARRECTANGULOGRIS

  ; CALL DETENER_POR_TIEMPO

  MOV COLUMNA, 180
  MOV FILA, 175
  MOV AVANCEH, 5
  MOV AVANCEV, 5
  CALL DIBUJARCIRCULONEGRO

  ; CALL DETENER_POR_TIEMPO

  MOV COLUMNA, 150
  MOV FILA, 160
  MOV AVANCEH, 20
  MOV AVANCEV, 20
  CALL DIBUJARTRIANGULODORADO

  ; CALL DETENER_POR_TIEMPO

  MOV AX, 3         ; Regresar al modo de texto
  INT 10h

  MOV AX, 4C00h     ; Salir del programa
  INT 21h

END INICIO


Because the code shows only some white lines when compiled in DOSBox,I compiled it in DOSBox and it showed me some white lines. I expected it to show me an image of a door with its lock and I tried it in emu8086 and it compiled only the top part turns grey (or I get a black screen with a flashing dash that says C:\TASM>_ ).


or I get a black screen with a flashing dash that says C:\TASM>_

This is easiest to solve! Your code MOV AX, 3 INT 10h that performs "Regresar al modo de texto" comes too soon. Give yourself a chance to see the actual output on the screen by introducing a pause like via waiting for a keystroke:
mov  ah, 00h    ; BIOS.GetKeystroke
int  16h        ; -> AX
mov  ax, 0003h  ; BIOS.SetVideomode
int  10h

Although the names DIBUJARRECTANGULOGRIS, DIBUJARCIRCULONEGRO, and DIBUJARTRIANGULODORADO suggest drawing a rectangle, a circle, and a triangle, I only see an effort to paint some rectangular surface. It's a work in progress no doubt.
But why does that fail?

All the rectangles start at the top of the screen.
You don't use the FILA argument and seeing that your COLUMNA argument is the X coordinate, I'm expecting FILA to be your Y coordinate. The calculation would then have to multiply Y by 320 and add X:
  mov  ax, 320
  mul  FILA         ; Y
  add  ax, COLUMNA
  mov  di, ax


All the rectangles get skewed.
The lines that you draw on the screen must all start at the same X coordinate. Therefore the add di, 320 must execute with DI pointing to the starting pixel. An easy solution here is to preserve DI on the stack:
  push di
  rep stosb
  pop  di
  add  di, 320





 MOV CX, DX  ; Restaura CX a la base del triángulo
 MOV DH, 0
DIBUJAR_LINEA:
 MOV AL, 14h ; Color dorado
 STOSB       ; Dibuja un píxel
 INC DI      ; Avanza al siguiente píxel en la memoria de video
 LOOP DIBUJAR_LINEA


Why did you write MOV DH, 0? You don't use it aferwards.
And the DIBUJAR_LINEA loop is simply REP STOSB just like you had it in the other procs.
